# Time sensitive password reset link

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, reset-password

I want to send a reset password page link to user which will be valid for certain period of time? I have tried a few bits but didn't find a solution/
How can I create a time-based reset password link? I have tried using the identities user manager but it doesn't seem to work with .net 6.

Can you suggest some simplest solution?

`// Startup.cs

```
 services.AddIdentity<NewClientPortalUser, IdentityRole>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

// Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
   opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

// And then in service: Resetpwd logic`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a time-sensitive password reset link by using the DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions in the Startup.cs file. This will allow you to set a TokenLifespan, which is the amount of time until the reset link will expire.

In the Program.cs file, you can add the following code to configure the TokenLifeSpan:

```
builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(opt =>
   opt.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

Once you have set the TokenLifespan, you will need to add the code that will generate the reset password link in your service. You can use the `ResetPasswordAsync()` method to send the reset password link with an expiration time.

For example, if you want the reset link to expire after 1 hour, you can use the following code:

```
await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, "newPassword", TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

This will generate a password reset link that will expire after 1 hour.

Comment: ResetPasswordAsync method doesn't except 4 params :(

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>` and `DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions`.

```
public class CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<TUser>
                              :  DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider(
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider,
        IOptions<EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions> options,
        ILogger<DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>> logger)
                                       : base(dataProtectionProvider, options, logger)
    {

    }
}

public class EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
{
    public EmailConfirmationTokenProviderOptions()
    {
        Name = "EmailDataProtectorTokenProvider";
        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
    }
}
```

Then add it to the service container in the `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
{
    config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    config.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("CustomEmailConfirmation",
        new TokenProviderDescriptor(
            typeof(CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>)));
    config.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "CustomEmailConfirmation";
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<CustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider<IdentityUser>>();
```

You can read more about it in the official Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#change-the-email-token-lifespan).